# identify the viewcontroller that called a modal view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm calling a modal viewcontoller from a number of locations and when i close it i'd like to find out what view it is on top of so i can call a update function if it is this custom list i've made.

I'm wondering how i might call a method in the ViewController under the modal view.

Right now i've set up a delegate, but it doesnt seem to call the method that i've set up.

Please see code.

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface PICTSharePictViewController : PICTBaseShareViewController <PICTConnModalViewControllerDelegate>
```

**.m**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

           PICTConnModalViewController *cmodal = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"connModal"];
    cmodal.pictDelegate = self;
}

-(void)checkSwitches:(PICTConnModalViewController*)sender{
    NSLog(@"-----Check-----");
}
```

**And ModalView**

**.h**

```
@class PICTConnModalViewController;

@protocol PICTConnModalViewControllerDelegate
-(void)checkSwitches:(PICTConnModalViewController*)sender;

@end

@interface PICTConnModalViewController : PICTBaseViewController {

    __weak id <PICTConnModalViewControllerDelegate> sliderDelegate;

}


@property (nonatomic, weak) id <PICTConnModalViewControllerDelegate> pictDelegate;
```

**.m**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    [pictDelegate checkSwitches:self];
}
```

I get no errors or any warnings. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the View Controller that presented the modal View Controller by using the `-[UIViewController presentingViewController]` method on the modal/presented VC.

Comment: Hmm, something similar to this?  `[self presentViewController:cmodal animated:YES completion:^{}];` or is what you were suggesting different?

Comment: That method is how you *present* a modal VC. `[self presentingViewController]` is how you access the original *presenting* VC from the *presented* (modal) VC.

Comment: Ahh sweet Nick, I'll try it out

Comment: So, I couldn't seem to get it to call, but when I try this inside the modal VC `    NSLog(@"Presenting VC : %@", [self presentingViewController]);` i'm returned `(null)` Thoughts?

Comment: To present a modal view controller, you should be calling `[self presentViewController:cmodal animated:YES completion:nil]`, but I didn't see any code like that in your question. How are you making the modal VC show up on screen?